# Any way to solve text and formula combination exceeding margin

Tags: amsmath

In LaTeX, when writing a paragraph containing formula and text, it exceeds margin. Therefore, I have to align it manually. That is time-consuming and the result is not well justified. Any way to control this automatically?

```
\documentclass{article} 
   \usepackage{amsmath} 
   \begin {document}
       \begin{align*}
            &\text {Setup(}\lambda \text{).
            Generate system public parameters and master secret key. 
            Two generators } \\ &g \in G_{1} \text{and h} \in G_{2}, 
            \text {are randomly selected as well as a secret value} 
            \gamma \leftarrow Z_{p} \text {.Choose a}\\ &
            \text {number and the equation has the following properties} g_{1}\\ 
        \end{align*} 
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us an example of what you mean? I think the only way to break displayed equations manually is via the `breqn` package.

Comment: Please add the code, and add it to your question, not a comment.

Comment: It is too long and cannot be posted here as there is character limit.

Comment: As an example, I give a short code. There are so many lines in paragraph. Therefore, manually breaking line does not equal.

Comment: The example is no use on its own (for example without knowing the line width we can not tell where it breaks. Post a _complete_ document, it onlyt needs to have one paragraph but make sure that as posted it demonstrates the problem, and add it to the question in a code section (`{}` button in the editor)

Comment: why are you using `align` in that way???? as far as I can tell from your fragment there is no alignment and no display it should all just ne an inline paragraph with no `\\ ` manual linebreaks at all.

Comment: add code to the _question_ not to a comment (I did it this time)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section*{Setup}

Generate system public parameters and master secret key. Two generators
$g \in G_{1}$ and $h \in G_{2}$,
are randomly selected as well as a secret value
$\gamma \leftarrow Z_{p}$.
 Choose $a$

\end{document}
```